# Image picker in selfie mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to find a way to open the image picker view direcly in "selfie" mode. (To take have the camera showing the user's face)

Does someone has a trick to do that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply do this by setting two properties of `UIImagePickerController` like this -

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[picker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];
```

You need to set `Camera Device` to `Front` and need to set `Source Type` to `Camera`.